# Table Join with Greater Than and Less Than

Tags: sql

I have a work orders table as below and I need to join this table with a shift table to retrieve the name of the shift that a work order belongs to based on the time of the work order.

```
    Date    TimeOfEntry Plant   ManufacturingLine   OrderNumber
2017-06-13  11:56:58    3120    D19 100015234
2017-06-13  12:12:18    3120    MIX 100016098
2017-06-13  12:17:59    3120    D16 100015218
2017-06-13  12:21:01    3120    D19 100015234
2017-06-13  12:22:23    3120    D19 100016017
2017-06-13  12:43:52    3120    WW2 100015543
2017-06-13  12:45:49    3120    WW2 100015543
2017-06-13  13:00:26    3120    W43 100015574
2017-06-13  13:01:51    3120    PRE 100016148
2017-06-13  13:05:53    3120    MIX 100016095

    ----------------Shifts--------------------------

    Plant   Shift   StartTime   EndTime
    3101    Day         06:01:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000
    3120    Day         06:01:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000
    3150    Day         06:01:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000
    3160    Day         06:01:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000
    3170    Day         06:01:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000
    3101    Afternoon   14:01:00.0000000    22:00:00.0000000
    3120    Afternoon   14:01:00.0000000    22:00:00.0000000
    3150    Afternoon   14:01:00.0000000    22:00:00.0000000
    3160    Afternoon   14:01:00.0000000    22:00:00.0000000
    3170    Afternoon   14:01:00.0000000    22:00:00.0000000
    3101    Night       22:01:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
    3120    Night       22:01:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
    3150    Night       22:01:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
    3160    Night       22:01:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
    3170    Night       22:01:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
```

The logic I want to use is If (TimeOfEntry is between Shift.StartTime and ShiftFinishTime) Then Shift.Shift.

Any idea how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the units of the `TimeOfEntry` column?  I don't recognize it as being anything familiar.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: Please tag *which* sql  - e.g. MySql, SqlServer, Postgres etc. It looks like someone has encoded TimeStamp as an integer `HHMMSS` - this isnt a good idea as it is easy to 'break' the domain with a value like `256162`. Many RDBMS support a native "Time of Day" data type, which would be well suited here.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider encoding your intervals using a *semi-open* interval. Most common would be inclusive start, exclusive end. That way your intervals clearly cover gaps by having the end of one precisely equal to the start of the next. At the moment, anything that happens at, say, 06:00:32 isn't covered by *any* of your shifts.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Output above is from SAP. So I created a view with proper date time columns.

Comment: `from workorders as wo join shifts as s on ws.Plant = s.pPlant and wo.TimeOfEntry  between s.StartTime  and s.EndTime`

Comment: With  "from SAP" do you mean you are using SAP HANA? Or an SAP application that uses some other relational database like Oracle or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because of the night shift.

You can use a `join`, but with special logic:

```
select wo.*, s.shift
from workorders wo join
     shifts s
     on wo.plant = s.plant and
        ((s.starttime < s.endtime and
          TimeOfEntry between s.starttime and s.endtime
         ) or
         (s.starttime > s.endtime and
          TimeOfEntry not between s.endtime and s.starttime 
         )
        );
```

Comment: You're a legend!